# Align button group right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This button-group just doesn't want to be aligned. I've tried to add pull-right, text-right, float-right bootstrap classes to `btn-group` div. I've tried to change text-align, padding, margin, float css properties for `buttons` class. Nothing helps. Only if I set padding-left value like `padding-left: 28px`. But that's not what I'm looking for. I need a solution for general case but not to experiment with how much pixels needed for padding-left value.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row issue">
  <div class="title col-md-7">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons btn-group col-md-5">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">PR</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DEL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap by default applies float:left to buttons in a button group. But overwriting that with float:right works perfectly fine ... if it didn’t for you, then you didn’t do it right.

Comment: @CBroe but it crashes appearance because inverts everything.

Comment: Well that’s how float works, yes. If you do not want that effect, you don’t want float. Overriding the float with none would make it possible to then use text-align on the parent element, https://jsfiddle.net/Lhfhaa2a/

Comment: @CBroe Hmm, I didn't expect this but it still looks cool :) Thank you much. I think I need to dig css docs for a while to understand core concepts better. Thank you also for expressing my weak sides. Best wishes. 
P.S. You may push an answer if you want. Then I could make it main answer and earn you some reputation. Or I can do it myself if you don't care of such vanities :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap by default applies `float:left` to buttons in a button group. But overwriting that with `float:right` works perfectly fine ... but than you will have the effect of the elements showing up in reverse order.

If you don’t want that, you can set `float: none` - and use `text-align` on the parent element to align the inline buttons.

```
.buttons { display: block; text-align: right; }
.buttons .btn { float: none; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhfhaa2a/1/

I added `display:block` for the parent element as well here, so that it takes the full width on smaller screen resolutions, too (it originally has `display: inline-block` set, but that would make it as wide as its content requires only - and if it is only as wide as the buttons make it, you can’t “align” them to either side any more.)

Answer (score 9):

bootstrap 4

```
  <div class="text-right"> 
      <div class="buttons btn-group col-md-5">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">PR</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DEL</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I created a [quick fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05wheg3k/) to demonstrate the difference between using `text-right` and `float-right`.

Answer (score 1):

The *flexbox* method is superior to the *float* method, which might cause unwanted side-effects.

### Bootstrap `v5`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class='row g-0'>
  <div class='col-md-5 w-auto ms-auto'>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">PR</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DEL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Bootstrap [`v4.6.0`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/#notation):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class='row no-gutters'>
  <div class='col-md-5 w-auto ml-auto'>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">PR</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">DEL</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. I'm new to Bootstrap and flexbox, so just wondering which class or attribute here makes it right-aligned? Seems `g-0`, `w-auto`, and `ms-auto` are only for spacing/margins, not alignment?

Comment: @ReversedEngineer - toggle the classes in devtools and learn which does what ;) hint - `margin` is imperative for the trick

Comment: Ok, I think I get it: w(idth)-auto means take up the whole width, and m(argin)s(tart)-auto means fill up the margin on the start (left) side, which pushes the content to the right-hand-side. You motivated me to figure out how to "toggle the classes in devtools" - very cool! And thank you vey much!

Answer (score 0):

flex is the best way:

```html
   

 <div style="display:flex">
      <div>  <button>PR</button></div>
      <div> <button>DEL</button></div>
 </div>
```

This aligns the buttons. You can play around this. Do you want spaces? aligned right?

Comment: Thank you. But all I need is to align button group to right in col-md-5 column. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: DId you try what i wrote above? needs to work perfect. can you send me what not working with this?

Comment: No @simi, I didn't try it because of the reason mentioned above. I didn't need any solution but a solution that doesn't change my grid system. By the way, the problem is already solved. You can see the preferred answer for details. Anyway, thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: The title of the question is "Align button group **right**". These are aligned **left**. My downvote.